# Firebase return one value from a document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access a single value in a document from Firebase's Firestore DB.

I can put in a string at CoreInfCall and print whatever value from that document into the terminal, but I cannot figure out how to return it in a way that makes it useable in the program. I have tried replacing print with return, and assigning a variable where print is and then assigning that to an separate variable which is then returned and neither work.

```
func fetchU_CoreInf_X (CoreInfCall: String) {

   let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid
   
   let ref  = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("Users").document(uid!).collection("colCoreInfo").document("docCoreInfo")
       
       ref.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
           if let documents = snapshot?.data() {
               print(documents["\(CoreInfCall)"]!)
           } else {
       print("No Documents")
      }
   }
}
```

I tried applying return functions in various places. I am expecting to be able to extract single key:value pairs from the firebase document (apparently you have to go through all the k/v pairs when you access a doc, but I just want to return one).

---

Following up on input from the comments, the .get approach didn't work for me either, here is the code I am using, maybe I misapplied it. Even copy-pasting Firebase's model code didn't work, and presents the error quoted below, suggesting I am missing something extremely fundamental. I have all the imports I think I need in place though (Firebase and FirebaseFirestore).

For example, the code below trying to see if someone has a pet or not, gives the error "Value of type 'DocumentReference' has no member 'get'"

func GetPet() -> String {

```
    let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid
    
    var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
   var HvPetout =  db.collection("Users") .document(uid).collection("colHobbies").document("docHobbies").get("inpHvPet") as? String ?? "no HvPetval"
    
    return HvPetout as! String
}
```

Comment: The snapshot give you an array you can take the “first” one and use a “completion handler” you can’t “return” becuase this is an asynchronous function

Comment: @loremipsum The snapshot is not an array, it's a snapshot, and in this case, the OP is using `getDocument` so the snapshot will contain a single document. Also, where are you seeing a `return`?

Comment: OP, you can easily access the fields within a document directly. For example, suppose the document has a field `name` within it. Here's how to read that `let name = someDoc.get("name") as? String ?? "No Name"`. Probably a good idea to go through the Getting Started Guide but here's the link to [Get Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: @Jay the OP says “they tried applying return”

Comment: @Jay NP I missed the getDocument part.

Comment: Thank you both for the input; Jay, I had taken a look at the Getting Started Guide before and the .get("name") approach always throws the following error: Value of type 'DocumentReference' has no member 'get'. Even copy+pasting the code from Firebase doesn't work for me. Unclear where I am messing up. I will amend the OP to reflect. Thank you both so much, I really appreciate the responses

Comment: Two important things. 1) This is how a document is read `docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in` and then within the closure, this `let name = document.get("name")...`. The error you're getting is because you're attempting to getDoc on the docRef, not the document itself. getDoc is done within the closure as shown in the example code. 2) See @loremipsum comment about about using 'return' within a closure as you cannot do that from a closure.